# How do i make working custom css in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've added custom css in ionic+angular which is working absolutely perfect with browser and its devices, but while i am generating apk for android device custom css is not working in android.

I am running this command to generate APK : ionic cordova run android

For more information i attached ionic version and index html screenshot.

[version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRhaR.png)

[Index.Html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3V2N.png)

Comment: For generic `css` please use `app.scss` and if you want to add another css/scss file, do include it in `app.scss` or `index.html`

Comment: @AbdulBasit I already included css path in index.html but still didnt worked, please refer attched Index.html screen shot

Comment: have a look https://imgur.com/a/ObxVfad, add your `css` file in generic `app.scss` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that "appStyle.css" file is written with S uppercase. Windows machines are case insensitive and Linux Machines (Android) are case sensitive.

Second, make sure that you're changing the index.html at `src` folder, not at `www`. Because `www` is the generated files and it is rewritten every build.

At last, as Abdul said in the comment, you should import your CSS files at `app/app.scss`.

```
@import '../assets/css/font-awesome.min';
```

I recommend you to put the css files outside from assets, which is recommended only static files, like images.